# PHP class -- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, class, syntax-error

I have a php class code like this:

```
class Foo{
  const ERROR_CODE = '404';
  public $public_ex = 'this is public';
  private $private_ex = 'this is private!';
  protected $protected_ex = 'this should be protected'; 
  public function getErrorCode() {
    return self::ERROR_CODE;
  }
}
$foo = new Foo;
$foo_json = json_encode($foo);
echo $foo_json;
```

And it shows:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in xxx.php on line 4
```

What should I do to make it run?
Thank you very much!! > <

Comment: [Cannot replicate the error you've give with the code provided.](http://3v4l.org/nbdaP) Unless you're running <5, but then again, not the same error.

Comment: Which line is #4 in the original file? There are no problems associated with your private variable example as listed above. Is this the entire file or just part of it?

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me... is the parse error in this code or in a different file? which file is xxx.php?

Comment: Show us your xxx php, because the code you posted is valid php code.

Comment: It's the code of xxx.php...Orz　It seems like it only doesn't work for me..(?) T_T